# How to identify the corrects step to complete 3NF?

Tags: database, computer-science, functional-dependencies, 3nf, bcnf

This is an example from a textbook:
Consider the relation R (A ,B ,C ,D ,E ) with FD’s AB -> C,
C -> B, and A -> D.

We get that the key is ABE and ACE. With decompositions: ABE+=ACE+=ABCDE.

How do you check minimality? I know that AB+=ABD and the textbook says that because AB+ does not include C. Then it is minimal. C+=AB and A+=AD are also minimal. But I do not know why. *How do you check minimality?*

Also, do we have to find all the FD's besides the ones given to check whether to perform 3-NF or not?

We then check if AB -> C can be split into A -> C and B -> C, we notice that these do not stand on their own so AB -> C is not splittable.

We are left with the final relations: S1(ABC), S2(BC), S3(AD) and the key (since not present) S4(ABE) (or S4(ABC)). We then remove S2 because it's a subset of S1.

If it is in 3NF and there are no violations, then why do they split the original relation into: S1(A, B, C), S2(A, D), and S4(A, B, E).

Book name and page: Ullman's Database Systems page 103

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do you check minimality?

The authors don't use the word *minimality* here. To check for the *minimal basis*, follow the procedure in the first two paragraphs of example 3.27. It boils down to

- ". . . verify that we cannot eliminate any of the given dependencies."
- ". . . verify that we cannot eliminate any attributes from a left side."

> Also, do we have to find all the FD's besides the ones given to check whether to perform 3-NF or not?

That question doesn't really make sense. 3NF isn't something you perform. The example in the textbook has to do with the synthesis algorithm for 3NF schemas. The synthesis algorithm decomposes a relation *R* into relations that are all in at least 3NF.

The synthesis algorithm operates on the FDs you've been given. In an academic setting, as you might find in a textbook, the assumption is that you've been given enough information to solve the problem. In real-world applications, you might be given a set of FDs from a business analyst. Don't assume the analyst has given you enough information; look for more FDs.

> We then check if AB -> C can be split into A -> C and B -> C, we notice that these do not stand on their own so AB -> C is not splittable.

No. You *verify* (not *notice*) that you can't eliminate any attributes from a left side. Eliminating A leaves B->C; eliminating B leaves A->C. Neither of these are implied by the three original FDs. So you can't eliminate any attributes from a left side.

> If [the original relation] is in 3NF and there are no violations . . .

The original relation is *not* in 3NF. It's not even in 2NF. (A->D)